# Date of month returning incorrectly in moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to get the datetimestamp and get the date of the month out it. When i am fetching the datetimestamp i am getting "2020-11-04T00:41:21.944Z" and when i am trying to get the dateOfMonth I am getting 3 where i should have got 4 i believe if it fecthes from timestamp. I am in CDT timezone, and i am beliveing it is giving me dateTimestamp in UTC format and dateofMonth in CDT format. Current time i am writing this post is 6.47 pm CDT (Chicago time zone). Please some one help me understand this, I am struggling very hard.

```
var moment = require('moment');

dateTimestamp = moment();
console.log(dateTimestamp);  // gives "2020-11-04T00:41:21.944Z" -> UTC time
dateOfMonth = dateTimestamp.date();
console.log(dateOfMonth); //gives 3 where as i was expecting it to fetch 4 as 4th of Nov
```

Comment: you need to get the UTC date rather than local date ... your local date is much of the time one less than UTC, being in that timezone you are in

Comment: @JaromandaX - How do we get the UTC date, can you please give me an example

Comment: no idea in momentjs ... in plain javascript you'd use [new Date().getUTCDate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCDate)